# multi level conditional statements in r

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm pretty new to R so please forgive me if this issue has been tackled in previous threads (perhaps in language I don't yet understand).

I'm trying to generate a new vector (df1$response_accuracy) based on 2 conditions. The first is that values from the vector `df1$Facial.expression` lie between 1 and 4, and that values from the vector `df1$Evaluations` equal "Like". Cases matching this criteria output "Correct" into the new vector and "Incorrect" otherwise. The second argument contains a similar set of conditions but for a different set of values in each vector (see below). Here is my code:

```
df1$response_accuracy <- 
ifelse(df1$Facial.expression == 1:4 & df1$Evaluation == "Like", "Correct", "Incorrect",                      
ifelse(df1$Facial.expression == 5:8 & df1$Evaluation == "Dislike", "Correct", "Incorrect")
)
```

The following error message is generated after running the script:

> Error in ifelse(df1$Facial.expression == 1:4 & df1$Evaluation ==
>   "Like",  :    unused argument (ifelse(df1$Facial.expression == 5:8 &
>   df1$Evaluation == "Dislike", "Correct", "Incorrect"))

I am aware the problem could relate to the accepted nesting formats supported by ifelse statements, but cannot find one that suits my command structure.

Thanks in advance for help on the matter.

Comment: df1$response_accuracy <-
 ifelse(df1$Facial.expression == 1:4 & df1$Evaluation == "Like", "Correct", 
         ifelse(df1$Facial.expression == 5:8 & df1$Evaluation == "Dislike", "Correct", "Incorrect")
  )

Comment: @Wyldsoul Consider the meaning of `df1$Facial.expression == 1:4` more carefully.

Comment: @Imo, I see:   df1$response_accuracy <-
  ifelse(df1$Facial.expression %in% 1:4 & df1$Evaluation == "Like", "Correct", 
         ifelse(df1$Facial.expression %in% 5:8 & df1$Evaluation == "Dislike", "Correct", "Incorrect")
  )

Answer (score 0):

what about this?
I can see 2 mistakes, first if you want to be between 2 values you have to do this way x>=1 & x<=4.
Then what do u want to do should return 2 vector not just 1... and then you have to compare this 2 vectors. So logically u have 3 ifelse.
Here a working example..

```
#just building sample data
x<-1:10
y<-sample(c("Like","Dislike"),10,replace=TRUE)


ans1<-ifelse(x>=1 & x<=4 & y=="Like",T, F)
ans2<- ifelse(x>=5 & x<=8 & y== "Dislike", T,F)

output<-ifelse(ans1 & ans2,"Correct", "Incorrect" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have nested `ifelse`-s. The syntax is `ifelse(test, yes, no)`. So you need to disentangle them

Comment: you can, it just gets awfully messy

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers and comments. I managed to find a solution by coming away from `ifelse` and creating a value called `'correct_cases'` instead. I then coerce this command via an indice after generating a generic vector `df$response_accuracy`; see below

```
correct_cases <- (df1$Facial.expression %in% 1:4 & 
df1$Evaluation == "Like") |
(df1$facial.expression %in% 5:8 & 
df1$Evaluation == "Dislike")

df1$Response_accuracy <- "Incorrect"

df1$Response_accuracy[correct_cases] <- "Correct"
```